# Should not there be "accused" instead of "prisoner" in this definition?

Tags: word-usage

I read a definition of "dock" in "Merriam Webster dictionaries" which was:

The place in a criminal court where a prisoner stands or sits during trial

I suppose there should be "accused" instead of "prisoner" in the definition. It's a trial. He's still to be found guilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Accused** would certainly be appropriate there, as would **defendant**, but **prisoner** isn't necessarily wrong, because it doesn't imply that the person has been convicted.

Many people are held in prison before and during their trials, so they can be referred to as **prisoners**, even though the legal proceedings haven't determined their guilt.

It's possibly more accurate to call these people **detainees** than prisoners, but they're commonly referred to as prisoners.

Edit: all this is from a U.S. perspective; it may be different in other English speaking countries.

Comment: It's also quite possible that the person in the courtroom *is* a convicted prisoner. They may be in court again because they are appealing their sentence.